# Error when using jQuery with WordPress theme

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I purchased a WordPress theme and have begun customizing it. There is one aspect of the theme that I cannot for the life of me figure out why it is redirecting to a page called "undefined".

[sdndaily.com](http://sdndaily.com) is the site in question.

```
!function (a, b) {
'object' == typeof module && 'object' == typeof module.exports ? module.exports = a.document ? b(a, !0)  : function (a) {
    if (!a.document) throw new Error('jQuery requires a window with a document');
    return b(a)
}
 : b(a)
}('undefined' != typeof window ? window : this, function (a, b) {
var c = [
],
d = c.slice,
e = c.concat,
f = c.push,
g = c.indexOf,
h = {
},
i = h.toString,
j = h.hasOwnProperty,
k = {
},
l = '1.11.1',
m = function (a, b) {
    return new m.fn.init(a, b)
}
```

In the top right corner there is an envelope icon that uses JavaScript to drop down a section to insert your e-mail. Shortly after clicking it, you are redirected to a page titled "undefined" and firebug spits an error:

```
Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
```

Comment: The anchor tag around the envelop doesn't have an href. It's behaving as though some js is assuming that the attribute will be there. Hence, the value undefined is being caste to a string of "undefined."

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to turn the a tag below into a span. I tested this on your site and it works like a charm:

```
<div id="collapse-trigger">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" class="collapse collapsed" data-target="#newsletter">
    <i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i>   </a>
</div>
```

Becomes:

```
<div id="collapse-trigger">
    <span data-toggle="collapse" class="collapse collapsed" data-target="#newsletter">
    <i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i>   </span>
</div>
```

Alternatively, find the action handler JS functions and add the event parameter and event.preventDefault(); on top of the function:

```
$('your_selector').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    ...
})
```

Comment: So I am trying to find where that line of code is generated from. I opened all the php, css and .js in notepad++ and did a search all for "<a data-toggle" for example and it returns 0 results. I am new to php but it seems like this html has to be in the source files somewhere right? I clearly see it when I views source code after php has ran it's loops.